# How to make FileZilla open all the required files with one click

Tags: webserver, ftp, text-editors, filezilla

Is there any way of configuring FileZilla so that I can open all the files on a server that I use to edit with just one click. For example if the files are like this:

- `/home/abc/def/one.txt`
- `/home/abc/def/yet/another/directory/two.txt`
- `/home/abc/def/ghi/yet/another/directory/three.txt`

Then it is very time-consuming to navigate through each directory and open the required files. These are only 3 files but what if we have around 10 to 20 files? Yes, copying the `path` of the directories is one thing. But something that is built-in so that I can just click a button like `open all the required files of this connection` and it opens all the files in the editor (as set in FileZilla preferences) then that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my reserach you can't do that in Filezilla now (2013.10.21), all of you could do that go to [Filezilla Track](http://trac.filezilla-project.org/) and open a feature request ticket for this. And maybe write the link of the ticket back here, so others whos have the same problem could give an eye on the progress.